# A lot of status bars make runtime error '1004' methods 'status bar' of object'_application' failed. How to fix It?

Tags: vba, excel, statusbar

I just make validation program with vba macro excel.

The program is made to see a lot of errors. so i can fix the errors.

I use message box also message in status bar. I use status bar because, I want my message keep showing, when I click the sheets which contain error. message box doing well, but A lot of error messages in status bars make runtime error '1004' methods 'status bar' of object'_application' failed. my program stop working.

this is my code:

```
Private Sub commandbutton1_click()

Dim error As String

    error = ""

    If (baby_less_1_year = True) And (immunization_exp = 0) Then
        error = error & "(1) immunization exp shouldn't be empty" & Chr(10)
        End If

    If (saving_bank= True) And (finance_exp = 0) Then
        error = error & "(1) finance bank exp shouldn't be empty " & Chr(10)
        End If

    If (handphone = True) And (pulse_exp = 0) Then
        error = error & "(1) pulse exp shouldn't be empty" & Chr(10)
        End If



If error = "" Then Application.StatusBar = "clean" Else Application.StatusBar = error

If error = "" Then MsgBox "sudah clean", vbInformation Else MsgBox error, vbCritical
```

How to fix It??? Is there any tricks to use status bar message which contains a lot of message?

Comment: The status bar is limited to 255 characters. Perhaps you should write your messages to the `Immediate` window instead?

Comment: @CLR note, the immediate pane is limited to ...255 lines ;0)

Comment: You're [ab]using the status bar to provide user feedback for input validation. The only solution is to find another way to provide user feedback.

Comment: is there any alternative which doesn't restrict the characters?

Comment: How can i make another way to provide user feedback? I'm sorry because i just learn macro vba..

Comment: How about making a worksheet (or table, or section of a worksheet, ..whatever) that lists all validation issues? [It can look pretty with conditional formatting cleverness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0WSj.png) (that one actually doesn't use any VBA code)

Comment: A non-modal form with a text box would work.  The user can leave it showing after your code is finished, so they can fix the validation issues.

Comment: that's sounds great, but  I want the error message keep showing in the current open sheet, so i can fix it directly.. @mat'smug

Comment: That's quite exactly what I have here. An order form, with a validation section on the same sheet (but outside the print area) with an `=If` formula for each field that needs to be validated. Heck, I even have the order form's header showing a bright red banner when the form is invalid.

Comment: do you have any example file to solve my issues? with the example file maybe i could more understanding :'(

Answer (score 0):

`Application.StatusBar` allows a maximum string length of 255 chars.

You can try this:

```
Dim msg as String
msg = ...
Application.StatusBar = Left(msg, 255)
```